# Mongoose NPM Install Fails Windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows-8, mongoose, installation, npm

When I do an 'npm install mongoose' I am unable to install it. I have MongoDB installed (which shouldn't matter...) and I have the mongodb package for npm installed. I get

```
 npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\workspace\HQC Apps\private\Ben\ticketpicker\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\colors\c
olors.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd C:\workspace\HQC Apps\private\Ben\ticketpicker
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path C:\workspace\HQC Apps\private\Ben\ticketpicker\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\colors\colors.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: mongodb@0.9.7-2-5
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux,darwin,freebsd
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd C:\workspace\HQC Apps\private\Ben\ticketpicker
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\workspace\HQC Apps\private\Ben\ticketpicker\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Lemme know if there is anything I can Do!

Comment: If I force the install (add the -f param) it works?

Comment: Does it work anyhow ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed an old version of mongodb.
Try installing the latest version of mongodb.

If your machine is 64bit, install latest 64bit versions of node.js and mongodb.

Do an `npm cache clean` first.
Then run 'npm install mongoose'.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should instal it from developer console. Please open **Developer Command Prompt** which is installed by Visual Studio and install it from it. You can then use

```
npm install -g mongoose
```

Which will download, compile required files with node-gyp and install mongoose into node global scope. When you try to install it from normal console, compiler could not find files neccessary to compilation. Developer Command Prompt includes required file paths in its path list.